# backlinks via intermediate link Google Search Console backlink checker

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, backlinks

I have searched the internet and this site but could not find any concrete answers to my question.

I have a number of these links pointing towards my website (see img), should I disavow these links, is it considered bad for my link profile...? What exactly does this mean? How does this impact link equity and which site gets the backlink credit?

Comment: Could you explain, in your question, what you mean by "backlinks via intermediate link" - are you referring to _cross domain canonicals_ (ie. `rel="canonical") as suggested in your "bounty description"? You mention "see img" in your question, should that be "image"? But there is no _image_? If you have an _old site_ (X) and a _new site_ (Y) then why are you not _redirecting_, rather than just stating the _canonical_? Is there a one to one page relationship between site X and site Y?

Comment: Where is the img?

Answer (score 1):

If your website is related with same Domain Content (Sports. Playing etc.) So you don't need to do anything while it will give an advantages towards your website in the form of **Link Juice.**

Let me give you the best advice as - Just think like if any user comes from rugbybetting upon your website then is it worth-full for him or not **(UX)**. If the answer is **Yes** then be relax you will get the advantages with these type of links.